# Python , Changing a font size of a string variable

Tags: python, fonts, font-size

I have a variable that gets sent to a email as text but the text is all pretty much a standard size with everything the same. I would like to add some emphasis to it as well as make it bigger and make it bold if possible. Here is the code I would like to edit.

```
  final_name = "Changes by" + str(name)+" ***"
```

I know it isn't much but I would like to know if it is possible if I can make a variable string bold and with a slightly bigger font size.

Comment: You may want to study first how rich email works; email can be sent as plain text or as a different format, these days usually as HTML. Once you've learned more about how to *send* HTML email, and you still have problems with that, I'm sure we can help you out here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am sending it as a MimeText but I all the variables and everything is being stored as a string that I just place on it to get it to work. I will learn some more but I feel like your answer is a bit vauge. But thank you none the less.

Comment: MimeText is plain text email, and you have no control over how large the text will be displayed, or any other styling. I tried to give you some pointers; the subject is rather complicated and involved and not easily condensed in a simple SO answer.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. I guess I will have to do some more research in the subject I thought it was something simple my mistake.

Comment: Where would you recommend I do research on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings don't have a font size. Strings store sequences of characters (unicode strings) or bytes to be interpreted as characters (byte strings).

Font size is an element of presentation, and is a function of whatever presentation and rendering system you are using.

As you mention an email, you could create a multipart email with an HTML part, and format it accordingly in that HTML document.

Answer (score 3):

If python is sending out the email through your SMTP server; You'll want to change the email type to html formatting by setting the content-type to `text/html`

```
# Build the email message
sender_name = "My script"
sender_email = "someEmail@company.com"
reciver_emails = ['receive1@company.com', 'receive2@company.com']
subject = "MY email subject"
message = "HTML <b>bolded</b> text"

email = ("From: %s <%s>\r\n"
         "To: %s\r\n" % (sender_name, sender_email, receiver_emails))

email = email + "CC: %s\r\n" % (cc_emails)
email = email + ("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
                 "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
                 "Subject: %s\r\n\r\n"""
                 "<html>\r\n"
                 "%s\r\n"
                 "</html>" %  (subject, message))
```

You can then add html type tags as the some of the answers have stated.

Comment: It's probably better to do it multipart, and have a plaintext part too.

Comment: @Marcin - What would be the advantage to that vs having it all within HTML and not applying any formatting?

Comment: If you wanted no formatting, why would you bother with HTML mail? The point of having multipart mail is that mail clients that can display the HTML can do so, and mail clients that can't (and those used by those who don't want HTML mail), can see the plaintext message. No-one wants to look at raw HTML markup.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't even think about that.  Thanks for the insight.