# Increase the font size and style of a string

Tags: python, font-size

I want to increase the font size of string to 36 and style italic through python code.
When ever i will run the code in command line it should show the string in font size 36 and style italic.

value = "Hello World !!!!"

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Font size and style, in what? In your IDE? In a GUI program?

Comment: No, there is no platform-independent way to do this, so without more information about your platform this cannot be solved.

Comment: No GUI, to show only on command line..In command line all the displayed characters have same font size, i want to show a particular string with bigger font size compare to others or you can say, i want to make it as a heading (in bigger and different style)

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324478/python-changing-a-font-size-of-a-string-variable

Comment: Short answer no its not, possible. Long answer it might be possible on some platform. But since you don't mention what your platform/shell is is not possible to answer the question. Edit your question to make it more answerable.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code is a mechanism for controlling output formats in many kinds of terminal but it does not offer control over fonts or sizes. If you target a particular kind of terminal you might be able to find one which does, but it's probably not going to be a solution you're very happy with. So with the information you have supplied, the short and simple answer is "no, generally speaking, it's not possible". Target a GUI instead of a terminal if you want to control aspects if the GUI presentation.